# How can I update a custom attribute in MS CRM when converting a lead to an opportunity?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have a new attribute on the lead and entity called 'Sales Channel'. When converting a lead to an opportunity I would like this information to be passed over, however I cannot find out how to edit the system workflow or create a custom one to accomplish this. Anyone ever try this before?

Comment: Is this programming-related...?

Answer (score 1):

Create an attribute mapping from the Lead to the Opportunity for the custom attribute.